# Awk command to grep data between two multi-line pattern based on condition

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk, grep

## Sample.xml :

`
        test point 
        
       lvl3 of id 1
       lvl4 of id 1

```
<tester>
   <level1 id="2"> test point </level1>
   <level2> </level2>
   <level3>lvl3 of id 2 </level3>
   <level4> lvl4 of id 2</level4>
   <level5> </level5>
</tester>

<tester>
   <level1 id="3"> test point </level1>
   <level2> </level2>
   <level3>lvl3 of id 3</level3>
   <level4>lvl4 of id 3</level4>
   <level5> </level5>
</tester>

<tester>
   <level1 id="2"> test point </level1>
   <level2> </level2>
   <level3>lvl3 of id 2 2nd occurance</level3>
   <level4>lvl4 of id 2 2nd occurance</level4>
   <level5> </level5>
</tester>
```

`
For the above mentioned sample.xml , I need to get the level3 and level4 tag only if the **Id** in level1 is **2**.
For eg : 
I should get the below answer when I search for **id=2**

```
<level3>lvl3 of id 2 </level3>
<level4> lvl4 of id 2</level4>

<level3>lvl3 of id 2 2nd occurance</level3>
<level4>lvl4 of id 2 2nd occurance</level4>
```

Comment: Have tried the below one. `awk '/\<tester\>/,/\<\/tester\>/{print}' 1.xml | grep "id=\"2\"" ` which gave the following result `<level1 id="2"> test point </level1> <level1 id="2"> test point </level1> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/<tester>/{n;/<level1[ ]*id="2"/{n;n;N;p}}' input
```

Explanation:

```
sed                  # execute sed
-n                   # do not print unless explicitly stated
/<tester>/           # if this line contains <tester>
{                    # then 
n;                   # skip the line (read new line over the old line)
/<level1[ ]*id="2"/  # if this line contains <level1 [spaces] id="2"
{                    # then
n;n;                 # skip it, and skip the next line
N;                   # read another line but this time append
p                    # print the buffer
}                    # end if
}                    # end if
```

Comment: this works very well!!. but I was looking for awk . Could you pls explain your cmd ?

Comment: added explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend an xml parser like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). However that's not to say it can't be done using `awk`. Here's one way. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
/<tester>/ {
    r=""
    f=1
}

f && /<level1 id="2">/ {
    g=1
}

g && /<level[34]>/ {
    sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")
    r = r $0 ORS
}

/<\/tester>/ {
    if (g && r) {
        print r
    }
    f=g=0
}
```

Results:

```
<level3>lvl3 of id 2 </level3>
<level4> lvl4 of id 2</level4>

<level3>lvl3 of id 2 2nd occurance</level3>
<level4>lvl4 of id 2 2nd occurance</level4>
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '/<tester>/ { r=""; f=1 } f && /<level1 id="2">/ { g=1 } g && /<level[34]>/ { sub(/^[ \t]+/, ""); r = r $0 ORS } /<\/tester>/ { if (g && r) print r; f=g=0 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with blocks in awk, it is often convenient to clear RS.  I believe this does what you want:

```
awk '/id="2"/{print ""; split( $0,a,"\n" ); for( i in a) 
    if( match( a[i], "level[34]" )) print(a[i])}' RS= input
```